# Running monogame app on other pc than developed

Tags: c#, monogame

I would like to run monogame game on other pc than it was developed on. When i execute .exe file process starts and dies after 2 seconds without any output (even in command line).

I tried to attach openAL libs to project, to install openAL, to publish and install game. Nothing helped. For debugging i have added whole main code to try/catch, but still there is no output.

On machine where i developed this game, everything works fine.

What should i do to run monogame game on other pc? (monogame version 3.0)

Cheers

Comment: check your logs and event viewer on the 2nd computer to see what exceptions are being thrown. more than likely there is a reference missing, a file missing, or a version mismatch - but that is sheer guesswork since you haven't given us anything to work with. As it stands this question is unanswerable.

Comment: As far as I've experienced, all you have to do to publish, is build the solution in Release mode, and zip up the Exe, all DLLs, and the Content folder. Are you sure you've included all DLLs? Otherwise this would (as @user1666620 points out) likely result in a missing reference exception, that you can read in the Event viewer.